# How to write XPath for multiple sibling of div tag

Tags: html, css, selenium, xpath

I am writing XPath for the following piece of code:

```
<div class="line info">
        <div class="unit labelInfo TextMdB">First</div>
        <div class="unit lastUnit">
                <div class="line TextMd">Second</div>
```

How can I reach the second div tag by using the first div tag using the sibling concept?
I wrote my XPath like:

```
//div[contains(text(), 'First')]/following-sibling::div[2][contains(text(),'Second')]
```

But it's not working.
How do I reach the "second" by using the "first" div tag?
I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

```
//div[contains(text(), 'First')]/following-sibling::div[2]
--------------------------------------------------------^
```

There is no 2nd "following sibling" at this point. The `<div>` that contains the text `'Second'` is a *child* of the `div.unit.lastUnit`.

This means

```
//div[contains(text(), 'First')]/following-sibling::div[1]/div[contains(text(),'Second')]
```

---

Another way that is less dependent on document structure would be to say *"I want the first following `<div>` that contains the the text `'Second'`"*:

```
(//div[contains(text(), 'First')]/following::div[contains(text(),'Second')])[1]
```

but this might return results you did not want, exactly *because* it pays less attention to document structure.

Comment: Thank you ..It's working. I am learning selenium. How to get master in finding xpath.

Comment: @siri Just like with everything else - it takes a lot of practice. :)